# Why $(...).mask is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask

What I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function($){
 $(".time-input").mask("99:99");
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't need `$` as a parameter to the callback for `.ready`

Comment: Check that the path to `jquery.mask.js` is correct. Also check that you're not loading another version of jQuery.js after you include those scripts

Comment: @chazsolo nothing wrong with it though, it's  a valid argument

Comment: @charlietfl I realize as much, just noting that shadowed variables are usually cause for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

try using this instead:

`$(":input").inputmask();`

`$("#yourelement").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"});`

Comment: This is the only thing that fixed mine.